# Match user from list against filenames

Tags: csv, powershell

I have a long winded script that gets a user from an CSV file, matches user against a CSV filename from a specific directory.

The user is matched against this CSV file in this format `<data><samaccountname><text>.csv`

The aim here is to get an AD User from a list, then scan a folder with CSV Files in it and match against the user. From there restore the user AD attributes.

The issue here is that the output is always of the last user twice, I have REM out the export at the end so I can see what is on screen first.

```psh
Clear-Host
#Get username from users list and match against CSV file name.
$FDate = (get-date).ToString("yyyMMdd")
$Project = "<FolderPath>" #Project name used to setup folders and for reports etc
$ProjectRoot = "<path>\" # Backup folder
$RestorePath = $ProjectRoot + $Project #combined path for restoring
$UsersListFile = $ProjectRoot + '\Userlist.csv' #Userlist
$Results = @{} # Storage for all csv files
$PSObject = New-Object psobject
$Report = @() #For Export-CSV
$Results = gci $RestorePath -Filter '*.csv'

$i = 0
foreach ($File in $Results) {
  $i += 1
  Write-Host 'Number of passes - '$i
  Write-Host 'Current file processing - '$file.Name -for Green
  foreach ($User in (import-csv $UsersListFile)) {
    $SAM = $User.SamAccountName
    Write-Host 'Current User processing - '$SAM -ForegroundColor Magenta

    if ($file.Name -match $SAM) {
      Write-host "Filename and user $SAM match " -for Yellow
      $Row= New-Object psobject
      $ROW | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Name -value $SAM -force
      $Report += $Row

      foreach ($Attrib in (import-csv $restorepath\$file)) {
        #Write-host 'Attributes in file - ' $attrib.samaccountname $Attrib.mail -for Yellow
        #Use this to restore AD User data
      }
    } else {
      Write-Host "No match" -ForegroundColor Red
    }
  }
}
#$Report | Export-Csv $RestorePath'\Test.csv' -NoTypeInformation -Force
$Report | Sort-Object Name
```

Answer (score 1):

Updated script to move New-Object psobject to above $Row, so this creates a new object each time, rather then overwriting previous entry.